# base de datos mysql no se conecta con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quiero conectar mi página web a mi base de datos MySQL, con PDO. Lo hice en XAMPP y funciona bien, cuando lo subo a mi servidor, uso el MySQL  Database Wizard para crear mi nueva base de datos, importo lo que tenía en local y modifico mi archivo Db.php para colocar los datos de mi base de datos en el servidor, pero no funciona la conexión, me dice que el acceso está denegado.

He verificado mensajes anteriores en stackoverflow, y he probado cambiar localhost por el ip, y por el nombre del servidor, pero siempre me da el mismo problema, solo cambia que en lugar de poner localhost el mensaje de error pone el nombre de mi servidor.

El mensaje exacto que me da es:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'Beatrice11'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in

y mi código es:

```
 $username = 'Beatrice11';
 $password = 'Beatrice18090957';
 $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yogarage_Beatrice11', $username, $password );
```

Como pueden ver en estas imagenes tengo creada la BD, el usuario, y sus privilegios, no sé qué puede faltarme:

[image: base de datos y usuario]

[image: privilegios]

Comment: Según la imágen, el `$username` correcto es `yogarage_Beatrice11`

Comment: Oh, Dios, eso solo demuestra lo ciega que me puedo poner cuando no quiero ver el error tan obvio. Mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el username de  `$username = 'Beatrice11';` a  `$username = 'yogarage_Beatrice11';` con eso debería funcionar, sin problema.